# Cannot use certificate secret value stored in Key Vault in Azure Resource Template

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I am trying to deploy an Azure HD insight Spark template using Visual Studio. The HD insight cluster accesses a Data Lake and for Data Lake Storage i have created a service principal with a certificate. I have stored the certificate in Azure Vault as a **secret** and trying to access it in my Azure Resource Manager Template. However, it is throwing the following error `Service Principal Details are invalid`
I have downloaded the certificate from a running cluster and there is nothing wrong with the certificate. I always use this certificate to create clusters through the Portal.

```
 "reference": {
    "keyVault": {
      "id": "/subscriptions/e3f93473-xxx/resourceGroups/Production/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/myvault"
    },
    "secretName": "certificateNew"
  }
```

Comment: I don't think this is a certificate issue. If possible, you could check this [link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/655) Could use login your account with your certificate `Login-AzureRmAccount -ServicePrincipal -TenantId $tenantId -CertificateThumbprint $thumbprint -ApplicationId $azureAdApplication.ApplicationId`.

Comment: Your parameter syntax looks fine - Is the cert in the vault base64 encoded?

Comment: I am not sure if the cert int he vault is base64 encoded or not. Basically I downloaded this certificate when I created HD insight cluster using the Azure Portal

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and managed to solve it by using the Powershell command on [this page](https://hdinsight.github.io/ClusterCRUD/ADLS/adls-create-serviceprincipal-certificate-format.html) to convert the PFX certificate to a Base-64 string value. I then uploaded the string value to a secret in Key Vault.

```
$servicePrincipalCertificateBase64 = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes(path-to-servicePrincipalCertificatePfxFile))
```

There are several scripts available on Github that convert a PFX to Base-64 and upload it to a Key Vault that you specify. I tried some of them, but somehow they converted to a format that caused problems while depoying the ARM template. The method I mentioned solved the problem in my case.

Comment: While the document behind the link might answer the question you also should add the contents from there here to prevent it getting lost when the document is moved or deleted.

Comment: I did the same thing, But i am getting this error: Code: CertificateImproperlyFormatted
Message: The data retrieved from <my secret url> is not deserializable into JSON